# rm cannot delete files starting with "--"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rm

I have a script that creates files, and sometimes they end up having two dashes at the beginning. Is there any way to delete them? `mv` doesn't work either.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
$ ls
 --1355509766.jpg

$ rm --1355509766.jpg 
rm: illegal option -- -
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...
   unlink file

$ rm "--1355509766.jpg"
rm: illegal option -- -
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...
   unlink file
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The usual trick is

```
rm ./--1355509766.jpg
```

Update: here's what `man rm` has to say about this:

```
To  remove a file whose name starts with a '-', for example '-foo', use
one of these commands:

       rm -- -foo

       rm ./-foo
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `--` to separate options from parameters.

```
$ rm -- --1355509766.jpg
```

This works with other commands too. For example:

```
$ touch -- -v         # create a file called -v
$ grep foo -- -v      # grep for "foo" in file called -v
```

Answer (score 6):

Try file name with path:

```
$ rm ./--file.name
```

Example:

```
$ echo dgag > --test.txt
$ ls
--test.txt
$ rm ./--test.txt
$ ls
```

Comment: Yes , this worked great ....I had a file name that start with the hash sign #file_name# and this was how i deleted it rm ./#file_name#