# How to remove a file whose name starts with '-'

Tags: bash, shell, unix, rm

After a mistake in a script I ended up with a file whose name starts with a dash, `-`:

```
-myfile.txt
```

I tried so far:

```
rm -myfile.txt
rm: illegal option -- m
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...
       unlink file

rm "-myfile.txt"
rm: illegal option -- m
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...
       unlink file

rm "\-myfile.txt"
rm: \-myfile.txt: No such file or directory

rm \-myfile.txt
rm: illegal option -- m
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...
       unlink file

rm "-"myfile.txt
rm: illegal option -- m
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...
       unlink file
```

How can I delete this file?

Comment: __FAQ__: `rm -- filename`

Comment: Possible duplicates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917714/rm-cannot-delete-files-starting-with) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706196/how-to-remove-files-starting-with-double-hyphen)

Comment: thanks @ajp15243. I didn't find it when searching

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to @ajp15243 :
the answer is :

```
rm ./-myfile.txt
```

or

```
rm -- -myfile.txt
```

Comment: I think devnull deserves some credit for the `--` answer too :). You are encouraged to accept your answers to your own questions if that's what solved the problem. It will mark the question as solved for the next person who comes searching through SO for answers.

Comment: Sure, but I actually understood what he meant thanks to your post !
(I can accept my answer in 2 days!)

Answer (score 2):

Use the absolute pathname

Like rm /home/name/-myfile.txt

Answer (score 1):

you could always try the inode solution :

```
$ ls -al -i | grep me
2116530 -rw-rw-r--  1 user123 user123       0 Feb 27 12:39 me
```

and `2116530` is the inode of the file. Then you can use find to delete it

```
find ./ -inum 2116530 --delete
```

or even

```
find ./ -inum 2116530 -exec rm {\} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one
put your file name in "-"
eg:
rm "-myfile.txt"