# How to copy files with prefix '-'?

Tags: linux, file, shell, unix

I tried to copy all the files under a directory by simply issuing "cp * /dst_dir", but Shell showed:

```
~/git$ cp * ~/dst_dir
cp: invalid option -- 'o'
```

Then issued "ls -1" to list all the files, found the culprit is some files with prefix '-' like below.

```
   -count
   -sdds
   ...
```

Don't know how these files were generated, moreover I still can't find a way to remove or move these "-xxx" files.

```
   ~/git$ rm "-count"
   rm: invalid option -- 'c'
   Try `rm ./-count' to remove the file `-count'.
   Try `rm --help' for more information.

   ~/git]$ mv \-count  /tmp
   mv: invalid option -- 'c'
   Try `mv --help' for more information.
```

BTW, my shell is TCSH on RHEL 6.3,  "tcsh --version" shows:

```
    ~/git]$ tcsh --version
    tcsh --version
      tcsh 6.17.00 (Astron) 2009-07-10 (x86_64-unknown-linux) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,rh,color,filec
```

Anyone has any clue on this problem. Your help would be much appreciated.

### Update

Thanks all. I checked manual just now, found the official answer below:

```
   To remove a file whose name starts with a '-', for example '-foo',  
   use one of these commands:

      rm -- -foo

      rm ./-foo
```

Comment: By the way, most commands view the strings after the `--` as command arguments, not options

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove a file whose name starts with '-'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048216/how-to-remove-a-file-whose-name-starts-with)

Answer (score 5):

Try the command `rm -- -count`, or `rm ./-count`, check the man page of `rm`. Similarly, `cp -- * ~/dst_dir` to copy the files

Answer (score 2):

As always, specify a full path.

```
rm ./*
```